# GCloud, how to connect to MSSQL instance

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

This is straightforward but I haven't found out how to do it.

I started using Google Cloud and setup my PostgreSQL instance.
Now I need to migrate data from another MSSQL database, but not all of it.

I can migrate from my local computer connecting to both databases. 
Now I'd like to do the same directly from GCloud.

The posts that I've found describe how to create the whole MSSQL from GCloud, but I only need to connect to one that has been created.

However, I haven't found how to connect to MSSQL from there. Specifically, how do I install the necessary drivers?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to connect to MSSQL using what? (a program, python software that you wrote, ...)?

Comment: In my local computer I connect to it via Python.  However, I haven't gotten there yet.  Not running Python, and not having the corresponding drivers to connect to it.

Comment: Again, you are connecting to MSSQL using what? You are asking how to connect. You need to provide the `what` you want to connect with.

Comment: I see.  I haven't quite used Python in GCloud, but that's what I'd like to do.  I meant my question to be about the drivers that I need beforehand.  I'm editing the question.